# How to apply a client-side validation scheme using Yup Validation and Inertiajs?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, yup, inertiajs

I looked for some alternatives, but without success. Is it currently possible to insert a validation schema inside `useForm`?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';
import * as yup from 'yup';
```

```
type Props = {
  full_name: string;
  document: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  password_confirmation: string;
  accept_terms: string;
};
```

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  full_name: yup.string().required(),
  document: yup.string().required(),
  email: yup.string().required(),
  password: yup.string().required(),
  password_confirmation: yup
    .string()
    .required()
    .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], 'error...'),
  accept_terms: yup.string().required()
});
```

```
const { data, setData, processing, reset, errors } = useForm<Props>({
    **validationSchema: schema**
});
```

Comment: Not sure there is a way to do that. I think you can call the `validate` method of the schema yourself, in the submit handler, then use the `setError` method returned by `useForm` (see in [this part](https://inertiajs.com/forms#form-helper) of the doc).

Comment: @colinD thanks for the tip. I will do some tests.